# UAC elevation with python : unwanted system exit with elevate module

Tags: python, uac, sys, elevated-privileges

I'm trying to get an UAC elevation from within a python script. I need it to execute a command (I'm on windows 10) : `netsh winhttp set proxy xxxxxxx`, because it requires admin privileges.
To get them, I use this code I found :

```py
import os
from elevate import elevate
elevate(show_console=False)
os.popen('netsh winhttp set proxy 62.210.172.164:3128')
```

And this works perfectly, but then I got this :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TESTS 2.py", line 3, in <module>
    elevate(show_console=False)
  File "C:\Users\Elève\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\elevate\__init__.py", line 22, in elevate
    elevate(show_console, graphical)
  File "C:\Users\Elève\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\elevate\windows.py", line 89, in elevate
    sys.exit(ret.value)
SystemExit: 0
```

There is an unwanted system exit, that is pretty annoying, and it seems it's an error... Do any of you know how can I fix this ? Or got any other way to elevate my script with UAC privilages ? Knowing that I need to execute many command and don't want a confirmation of elevation for each one, I need to elevate the whole script... Thank you if you can help by any way !

Answer (score 2):

It will never work because I'm the owner of the IP 62.210.172.164 and I have a mistake in Squid configuration, so the proxy is now closed !

Comment: Was this even possible to find you there ? You're the owner ? Damn... But the issue is the same with any proxy, it works but then there's like a sys.exit that I don't want...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem ! First, I did pip show elevate in the cmd to get the location of the library script, then I opened it with python and just removed the last line, sys.exit(ret.value)... And that's all, it works perfectly now haha !

Answer (score 0):

I found the IP of my dedicated server on Stackoverflow by Googling the IP after I receive abuse report on my IP ... due to this mistake on squid server :(
So that's why I answer you :)

Comment: I don't see how this answer helps in any way.